# Default flash controls of camera app appears truncated

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

We are developing and iOS application and in one of the View Controllers UIImagePickerController is used to present the camera to the user. In the view controller there is a UIButton and in the event listener method we have the following code.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
imagePicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;


[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Camera app is presented properly, but the flash control titles are appearing truncated (Auto is appearing as Au..., Off is appearing as ...) as shown in the screen shots. It would be great if someone can help out. I'm guessing it's some app configuration issue, as the same code works in a different project.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]